# Unable to import react native custom module

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, module, export

I am using react-native ES6.
No compile time errors and no runtime errors.
I tried to import a Main module, but I don't have any errors. Here is the below code for Main.js file:

```
'use-strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-start', marginTop: 120}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20}}> Testing the router</Text>
      <Text> Testing the router</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Main;
```

Here is my first project file. I am trying to import Main.js file.

```
'use-strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';
import Main from './Main.js';

export default class FirstProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'App Title',
          component: Main
        }} />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstProject', () => FirstProject);
```

Comment: make sure your path is correct to inculde main.js

Answer (score 0):

Node.js-style single-value exports don't work. There, you export single value instead of object: `module.exports = Main`

Change it to `module.exports.Main`

a better syntax is to use `export default Main`

Comment: The issue is in react native, but not in node.js

Comment: @coolly Sure, react native :) I said the **Node.js-style** won't work

Comment: @coolly if this answer doesnt solve your problem, please let me know (so I can delete it) irrelevant answer should be removed